# ng-messages dynamic form name

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

The below snippet is in directive. I'm calling directive from controller. passing `formname="'AddressForm'"` from controller.

```
<div ng-messages="formname.Zip.$error"
     ng-show="(!formname.Zip.$pristine || formname.$submitted)">
</div>
```

I've tried `ng-messages="{{formname}}.Zip.$error"` and got below error

> Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{formname}}.Zip.$error] starting at [{::formname}}.Zip.$error].

How can i get formname ?

Comment: I also tried ng-messages="formname.Zip.$error", But formname is not getting replaced i.e) AddressForm.

Comment: You haven't given any solution.. can you please reply..